# mod_rewrite takes the rewritten URL as the base one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?mod=posts&action=cat&cat=$2
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?mod=posts&action=read&id=$2
```

When I point the browser to http://my-dev-server/posts/some-category/1/ the first RewriteRule is triggered and everything goes fine.
But then there I have a link like this one

```
<a href="post/post-title/10/"></a>
```

If I click that link it takes me to

```
http://my-dev-server/posts/some-category/1/post/post-title/10/
```

And it should be

```
    http://my-dev-server/post/post-title/10/
```

It is following the pattern of the first RewriteRule which is obviously wrong

What I am doing wrong here and how do I fix it without having to write absolute URLs?

Comment: But your `href` is relative to the current page, so it behaves as expected. Maybe you want `<a href="/post/post-title/10/"></a>`

Comment: I kinda simplified it, the problem is the site is not at http://my-dev-server/ but http://my-dev-server/some-directory/